# Sharing Facebook Login Credentials with Javascript API from server-side authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have a pretty simple (hopefully) question about using the Facebook Javascript API.
We are currently using the [server-side flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to log users into our site, this gets us an auth token and sets a cookie. I'm trying to use the Javascript API to query our logged-in users' friends lists, but I only get `undefined` out of every call to `FB.api`. Even `FB.getLoginStatus` returns `undefined`.

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/) leads me to believe that we have it backwards. Is it true that we need to do login using the client-side flow for us to use the Javascript API at all?

I thought that you would be able to use the cookie regardless of where it came from...

Answer (score 0):

did you also try the `FB.login` function? you could call it first, to make sure the user is logged in. try to call it in the FB.getLoginStatus callback function.

in the end it always depends on the project, but i would always try to use the javascript api for user authentication and login. keeps the user on the same page and looks better.

Comment: All I get is `FB.login() called when user is already connected.`
`FB.getLoginStatus` continues to return `undefined`.

Comment: no, i mean you can try to call the FB.login function yourself. but remember that this can only happen on mouseclick. well, in that case it will not work for you, i guess :( ... i do know that it works the other way around (login with the javascript api, refresh the page, check login with the php api).